# C# possible to use variable as property

Tags: c#, razor

I'm not sure if this is possible, but i'm trying to use a variable as a property while running a foreach.  I understand that this approach is probably not deemed clean and is due to poor data modeling, but i'm just wondering if this is possible.

**Model**

```
public class nameActivity
{   
    public string name {get;set;};  
    public int month {get;set;};    
    public int hours {get;set;};    
    public int billings {get;set;};     
}
```

**View**

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "hours", "billings" };

foreach (string i in stringArray)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <td>@item.name</td>
        <td>@item.month</td>
        <!--somehow use i variable in below td-->
        <td>@item.use_i_here</td>
    }   
}
```

Comment: you could use a dictionary.

Comment: Why not an array of lambdas instead like `Func<nameActivity, int>[] funcArray = { a => a.hours, a => a.billings };`

Comment: @juharr good suggestion.